# Swift Custom UITextField Not Editable

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I Have a Custom UITextField in my app,

```
class UnderLinedText: UITextField {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(1.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.21, green:0.13, blue:0.34, alpha:1.00).cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.textAlignment = .center
        self.borderStyle = .none
        self.isEnabled = true
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeueLT-Regular", size: 20)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

And I added it to my view controllers but its not working (cant edit it text)

```
class CommercialOrder: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate{

let bid = UnderLinedText()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        updateUI()

        bid.delegate = self

    }

 func updateUI(){
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
               scrollView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewSafeArea()
               contentView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges()
               contentView.autoMatch(.width, to: .width, of: view)
                contentView.addSubview(header)
                contentView.addSubview(bid_title)


        bid.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: bid_title, withOffset: 10)
        bid.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .trailing, withInset: 20)
        bid.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .leading, withInset: 20)
        bid.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 50)

        bid.text  = "Reciever mail"
}
```

I even added the **UITextFieldDelegate** make  **isEnabled** and **isUserInteractionEnabled** set to true bit its still not working

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Hope to help someone, my issue that the contentView has no Height which will effect on the scrolling (view not scrollable) so it will not get touch events just add the height or assign constraint to the bottom of last view to the contentView like in my case button

```
button.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .bottom, withInset: 30)
```

And thats it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint, that it may be connected with content/container view size!  I lost many hours searching for the reason, why I cannot change the text field content. In my case, the container, where text field was placed had no width..